# How to understand a range in hexadecimal

Tags: utf-8

I have this range:

U+F0000..U+FFFFD

Its for UTF, Private use characters. I understand F0000 to FFFFD means a range, but why the U+ is added in the beggining? what does it means?

Comment: It means it's a Unicode character.

Comment: It's Unicode's way of indicating it's a codepoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "U+" means it's a Unicode codepoint, just like "0x" means what follows is a hexadecimal number. The "U+" implies hexadecimal, so what follows is in hexadecimal notation, but represents a codepoint in Unicode.

In UTF-8, U+F0000 would be encoded as 0xF3 0xB0 0x80 0x80. U+FFFFD would be encoded as 0xF3 0xBF 0xBF 0xBD.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Unicode code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Character_properties) and the U+ prefix is how you write it.